# Powershell CMDLET return property values AD/User

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a simple property of a user in Active Directory.

the "wWWHomePage" property to be specific. I know this should be an easy task but the syntex isn't clear.

```
$result_displayname = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $search_base -f {(GivenName -eq $firstname) -and (SN -eq $surname)}
$result_displayname.wwwhomepage
```

Just does not work. What is the correct way to achieve this via cmdlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
$result_displayname = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $search_base -f {(GivenName -eq $firstname) -and (SN -eq $surname)} -Properties wwwHomePage 
$result_displayname.wwwhomepage
```

EDIT after comment:

from [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx)

This cmdlet retrieves a default set of user object properties. To retrieve additional properties use the Properties parameter. For more information about the how to determine the properties for user objects, see the Properties parameter description.

Comment: Thank you! So you have to define what properties to take with you, if only Microsoft had it that simple in their documentation.